# Rational distances from the corners of a unit square

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Is there a point all of whose distances from the corners of the unit square are rational?

Comment: It looks to be be an open problem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html

Comment: Discussed at some length in Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory.